# the meaning of the “netstat -aon | findstr 8766" command

Tags: windows, command

I used the `netstat -aon findstr 8766` command line to find out which process the 8766 port is occupied by, then I see the result as below

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8766           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    61.17.7.221:51976      ESTABLISHED     2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    61.17.7.220:51978      ESTABLISHED     2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    61.17.7.220:51979      ESTABLISHED     2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    61.17.7.220:51980      ESTABLISHED     2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    61.17.7.220:51981      ESTABLISHED     2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    61.17.7.220:51982      ESTABLISHED     2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7760      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7765      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7767      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7768      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7770      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7771      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    114.96.246.91:58203    ESTABLISHED     2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    118.50.81.168:7521     TIME_WAIT       0
```

I want to know what LISTENING , ESTABLISHED, FIN_WAIT_2, TIME_WAIT mean？ When I kill the process with pid of 2020，then I typed  the command `netstat -aon findstr 8766` and saw that some links were still there, the result is as follows

```
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7760      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7765      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7767      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7768      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7770      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    113.41.59.13:7771      FIN_WAIT_2      2020
  TCP    192.168.196.35:8766    118.50.81.168:7521     TIME_WAIT       0
```

Does this mean that the tcp request is not released?

Comment: Cleanup in kernel mode waiting for the other side of the connection?